# SELECT top 1 descending if DB contains current date data, else select top 1 ascending

Tags: sql, sql-server, selenium

I have a list of months that get populated into my DB. These months then get populated into a drop down list for a web Application. The client wants the current month to be the default option in the drop down list. However, the current month's data is not always available (Or ActiveFlag=Y in the database). So in that case, the client wants the default to be the first month of the year instead.

So I am testing that the drop down list and the DB table match using Selenium automation with C#. I have an SQL query that returns the Top 1 sorted in Descending order (This works to return the last active month in the year, because BroadcastMonthofYearNbr contains integers 1 through 12 month numbers):

```
SELECT top 1 CONCAT(RTRIM(left(M.Name, CHARINDEX(',',M.Name)-1)), ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), M.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), M.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')') 
            FROM [AudienceProjections].[dbo].[BroadcastCalendarQuarterMonthMap] QMP,
                AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear Y,
                AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarMonth M,
                AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter Q
            WHERE y.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = q.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
                AND q.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid = qmp.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid
                AND qmp.BroadcastCalendarMonthUuid = m.BroadcastCalendarMonthUuid
                AND M.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
                AND y.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
                AND q.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
                AND y.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE())
            ORDER BY qmp.BroadcastMonthofYearNbr DESC
```

The query above returns this:

`No Column Name
April (3/28/2016-4/24/2016)`

The current month for when I am posting this question is May 5th. Notice that the above query result returns April, not May. This is because May data has not yet been imported into the DB (See below table for distinction of the data being there or not. I.e Active versus Inactive). So my query wont work in this case. I would now need a `CASE THEN ELSE`, or an `IF EXISTS` type of function, to return January if this situation occurs

Here is the Month table that you can see have May as INACTIVE:

```
Name           StartDate    EndDate     ActiveStatus
January, 2016  2015-12-28   2016-01-31  ACTIVE
February, 2016 2016-02-01   2016-02-28  ACTIVE
March, 2016    2016-02-29   2016-03-27  ACTIVE
April, 2016    2016-03-28   2016-04-24  ACTIVE
May, 2016      2016-04-25   2016-05-29  INACTIVE
```

NOTE: I forgot about the situation of the current date being January, and if January isnt there, then the Year wouldnt be there yet either. So the condition in the query would need to take Year into account. The year table (BroadcastCalendarYear) also has an ActiveStatus column which can be used.

So if the year is also inactive, then return me a string that says "No data in DB for Year".

Comment: What is the question?   How to write a CASE expression?

Comment: How to write an expression inside of that query above to get the results I need. What I need is the current month if it is ACTIVE, else return first month of the year. Notice I added a table at the end to show the Active versus Inactive cells in the Month table

Comment: And what does this have to do with C# or Visual Studio (which you have tagged) ??

Comment: i was going to try and make a suggestion but the pre SQL-92 syntax is too much effort to decipher

Comment: Sorry, beginner at SQL. Can you suggest any edits to make my syntax more up to date?

Comment: Did you inherit this query from a previous developer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be able to adapt the following to your specific schema but here is an example as order by that would work. Note you may not need and should remove some of the where statements hard to know without knowing the dataset.

Also what month should be returned if it is January of the current year and nothing is active?  You may have to adapt the order by depending on that answer.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
    @Months
WHERE
    ActiveStates = 'ACTIVE'
    AND ????
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) = YearInt THEN 9999 ELSE YearInt END DESC -- Assumes you want to order by most recent to oldest and that youcould potentially have a future year loaded in the table.  Othwerwuse simply use YearInt DESC
    ,CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = MonthInt THEN 0 ELSE 1 END --Puts precedence on current month
    ,MonthInt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Month') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Month
CREATE TABLE #Month
(Year INT, Month VARCHAR(3), ActiveStatus CHAR(1))


INSERT INTO #Month(Year, Month, ActiveStatus)
VALUES(2016,'Jan','A')
,(2016,'Feb','A')
,(2016,'Mar','A')
,(2016,'Apr','A')
,(2016,'May','I')

;WITH x AS 
(
SELECT 
*,EOMONTH(CONCAT(Year,'-',Month,'-','01')) As Date
FROM #Month
)
SELECT 
*
FROM X
WHERE 
 -- current month is active or current month is inactive then first month of the current year
 Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND 
 (DATEPART(MONTH,Date)=DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AND ActiveStatus='A') OR     (1=DATEPART(MONTH,Date) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE     DATEPART(MONTH,Date)=DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AND ActiveStatus='I'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a long and convoluted solution, but it works.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.month = (SELECT left(M.Name, CHARINDEX(',',M.Name)-1) FROM [AudienceProjections].[dbo].[BroadcastCalendarMonth] M
            WHERE StartDate <= GETDATE() AND EndDate >= GETDATE() ) THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(left(t.Name, CHARINDEX(',',t.Name)-1)), ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), t.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')')  ELSE ( SELECT CONCAT(RTRIM(left(M.Name, CHARINDEX(',',M.Name)-1)), ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), M.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), M.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')')  FROM AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarMonth M WHERE  NAME = CONCAT( DATENAME(month,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), ', ', DATENAME(year,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0))  ) ) END month FROM    (                 
         SELECT top 1 left(M.Name, CHARINDEX(',',M.Name)-1) AS month, 
         M.Name, M.StartDate, M.EndDate
         FROM [AudienceProjections].[dbo].[BroadcastCalendarQuarterMonthMap] QMP,
                AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear Y,
                AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarMonth M,
                AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter Q
            WHERE y.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = q.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
                AND q.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid = qmp.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid
                AND qmp.BroadcastCalendarMonthUuid = m.BroadcastCalendarMonthUuid
                AND M.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
                AND q.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
            AND y.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
                AND y.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE())
            ORDER BY qmp.BroadcastMonthofYearNbr DESC) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using IF EXISTS, ELSE IF EXISTS, ELSE accomplishes all 3 conditions:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT CONCAT(q.DisplayName, ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), q.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), q.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')')
FROM AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear Y,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter Q
WHERE y.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = q.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
      AND q.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
      AND y.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND q.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND y.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
          AND Q.StartDate <= GETDATE()
          and Q.EndDate >= GETDATE()) 
SELECT CONCAT(q.DisplayName, ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), q.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), q.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')')
FROM AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear Y,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter Q
WHERE y.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = q.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
      AND q.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
      AND y.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND q.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND y.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
          AND Q.StartDate <= GETDATE()
          and Q.EndDate >= GETDATE() ELSE IF EXISTS (
SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(q.DisplayName, ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), q.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), q.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')')
FROM [AudienceProjections].[dbo].[BroadcastCalendarQuarterMonthMap] QMP,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear Y,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter Q
WHERE y.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = q.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
      AND q.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid = qmp.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid
      AND q.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
      AND y.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND q.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND y.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) ORDER BY qmp.BroadcastMonthofYearNbr ASC ) SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(q.DisplayName, ' (', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), q.StartDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), '-', STUFF(REPLACE('/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), q.EndDate, 101), '/0', '/'), 1, 1, ''), ')')
FROM [AudienceProjections].[dbo].[BroadcastCalendarQuarterMonthMap] QMP,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear Y,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter Q
WHERE y.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = q.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
      AND q.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid = qmp.BroadcastCalendarQuarterUuid
      AND q.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
      AND y.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND q.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND y.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY qmp.BroadcastMonthofYearNbr ASC; ELSE SELECT 'No Active quarters are in the database for the current year yet';
```